# Restrict entries in Calendar on F4 on date field, to get only year and month?

Tags: abap, dynpro

My requirement is, I have one select-options of type `sy-datum` on the selection screen.

Whenever a user presses F4 or uses the input help it will show a calendar. After double clicking the calendar, I should get the date in YYYYMM format that means only 6 digit date.

Comment: Can you give us any code you have so far?

Comment: what exactly do you mean "get only 6 digits" ? Do you mean that only 6 digits in the format YYYYMM should be displayed on screen ? Or Do you need just the month and the year for processing in your code ?

Comment: is it date you're after, or do you actually want financial period - which is in YYYYMM format?

Answer (score 2):

Use data element `KMONTH` instead, and make a custom F4 in your program, that uses function module `POPUP_TO_SELECT_MONTH`.